# URL Search, What is the difference between colon and equal?

Tags: elasticsearch

I found that Elasticsearch returns the same results for following queries.

> twitter/_search?q=user:kimchy
>
> twitter/_search?q=user=kimchy

However, If I query for nested object, Elasticsearch will return different results

> twitter/_search?q=location.address:us
>
> twitter/_search?q=location.address=us

What do colon and equal mean in term of Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `=` sign is part of the URL to separate the parameter and values in the query string.

The `:` sign is part of the [Lucene query expression language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) and is always used in the `q=` parameter of the query string.

So the first queries above are correct but not the second ones, even though they return data.